# Progressbar в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, progress-bar

Каким образом можно сделать загрузку `Progressbar` в момент записи данных в `базу данных`? Подскажите литературу или примеры.

***P.S*** Тут такого типа вопросы не любят, но все же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если записи вставляются в базу одним INSERT'ом сразу все, то никак. Если же записи последовательно откуда-то считываются и затем так же последовательно вставляются в базу, то ProgressBar можно рисовать в процессе чтения данных. Как именно его рисовать зависит от используемой вами графической библиотеки SWT, Swing или JavaFX. Например для Swing есть описание [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) в официальной документации. На этой странице [SWT Snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) есть описания использования визуальных элементов SWT и ProgressBar в том числе.

Comment: Ага, получается мне надо сделать какой нибудь зацикленный прогрессбар, что бы пользователь видел, что что от происходит и надо подождать. Так как запрос инсерт всего один (. А переделывать под несколько запросов...

Comment: У любого прогресс-бара есть т.н. режим Indeterminate Mode, когда ползунок не ползёт слева на право, а бегает туда-сюда, т.е. конечное время не определено, но что-то делается. Может быть рассмотреть этот вариант.